# Hide - display images randomly in Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hello I'm a beginner in Android and developing a game. Currently I am trying to make some images appear in the screen. I set the images in the layout to an array and I want indexes to generate randomly in order to display images. My problem is that In the beginning I want the images to be hidden then after the game start they appear randomly. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.evo;


import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Play extends Activity {

private ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3,iv4,iv5,iv6;
private ImageView[] IMGS = { iv1, iv3, iv3, iv4, iv5, iv6 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_game);

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);
    iv4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);
    iv5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);
    iv6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.player);

    IMGS[0] = iv1;
    IMGS[1] = iv2;
    IMGS[2] = iv3;
    IMGS[3] = iv4;
    IMGS[4] = iv5;
    IMGS[5] = iv6;



   while(true) {


       Random random = new Random();
       int rndIndex = random.nextInt(IMGS.length);



    }
}
```

Comment: _In the beginning i want the images to be hidden then after the game start they appear randomly_. Care to elaborate? How do you intend to start the game? And also, you use the same image for all `ImageViews`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the part you want the images to be hidden from the beginning, you can in your *xml* add a [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) for each imageView `android:visibility = "gone"`

In your code while(true) will make the layout unresponsive you should make a repeated thread or a timer which helps you to call the function repeatedly

About hiding and showing the imageViews

```
IMGS[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // to show the image
IMGS[0].setVisibility(View.GONE); // to hide the image
```

And i think you are using *drawable* instead of id to get the imageView from *xml*, and you are using the same image

Answer (score 0):

Use the setVisibility() method with the values VISIBLE/GONE.

```
iv1.setVisibility (View.GONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setVisiblity(int visibility)` to hide or show your ImageViews (as per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).

In your case, you should be able to do:

```
Random random = new Random();
int rndIndex = random.nextInt(IMGS.length);
IMGS[rndIndex].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To show the view. To hide the last one, I would suggest defining `rndIndex` with your array so that you could do

```
IMGS[rndIndex].setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

before the chunk of code above, meaning it would look more like:

```
IMGS[rndIndex].setVisibility(View.GONE);
Random random = new Random();
rndIndex = random.nextInt(IMGS.length);
IMGS[rndIndex].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Good luck!